# How can I use newton or L-BFGS as optimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I read a example of newton or lbfgs optimizer as follow:

```
optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, options={'maxiter': 100})
with tf.Session() as session:
    optimizer.minimize(session)
```

but I am confused because it's different from gradient descent optimizer as:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {....})
```

My question is CAN I USE THE L-BFGS OPTIMIZER AS BELOW EXAMPLE SHOWED?
If the answer is not, how can I use the L-BFGS optimizer at following code?

```
cost = compute_cost(ys, Z, W_soft, lambd)

train_soft = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_hat, 0), tf.argmax(ys, 0))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

mini_batch_data, mini_batch_labels, mini_batch_nums = batch_split(train_X, train_Y, batch_size)

paras_soft = {}
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(max_iter):
        train_soft_cost, _ = sess.run([cost, train_soft], feed_dict = {xs: train_X, ys: train_Y, keep_prob: 1})
```

Comment: Have you tried and what was the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

[`ScipyOpimizerInterface`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface) is a wrapper allowing `scipy.optimize.minimize` to operate in a tensorflow `Session`.

It accepts a `method` kwarg to which you can pass any of the methods outlined in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize).

```
optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, ..., method='L-BGFS-B')
```

You should understand that the applicability of a method depends on the constraints used. Consult the docs for more information.